# Collapsing a menu

Tags: jquery

I have a sub-menu that is displayed when this function is called (essentially when .sidr-class-menu_arrow is clicked on):

```
<li id="menu-item-169">
<a href="#">Main item with drop down
<span class="sidr-class-menu_arrow"><i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></span></a>
 <ul class="sidr-class-sub-menu">
   <li><a href="#">Sub item</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Sub item</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Sub item</a></li>
 </ul>
</li>



jQuery('.sidr-class-menu_arrow').on( 'click', function ( e ) {
        e.preventDefault();  e.stopPropagation();
        jQuery(this).addClass('sidrsubmenu_on');
        jQuery(this).parent().parent().find('.sidr-class-sub-menu:eq(0)').slideDown();
});
```

This works but once open I want to be able to click again on .sidr-class-menu_arrow and close the sub-menu, reversing the process.

I've tried this:

```
jQuery('.sidr-class-menu_arrow .sidrsubmenu_on').on( 'click', function ( e ) {
        e.preventDefault();  e.stopPropagation();
        jQuery(this).removeClass('sidrsubmenu_on');
        jQuery(this).parent().parent().find('.sidr-class-sub-menu:eq(0)').slideUp();
});
```

but to no avail.

Can someone point me in the right direction please? Thanks!

Comment: Add the code snippet with the problem, please.

Comment: Sorry, that's done.

Comment: Can you post your full code including css for better understanding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try slideToggle and toggleClass

```
jQuery('.sidr-class-menu_arrow').on( 'click', function ( e ) {
        e.preventDefault();  e.stopPropagation();
        jQuery(this).toggleClass('sidrsubmenu_on');
        jQuery(this).parent().parent().find('.sidr-class-sub-menu:eq(0)').slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: can you post this on jsfiddle?